# HTTPS on main domain works fine but on sub domain gives 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I recently got a COMODO EssentialSSL Wildcard  installed on a site. The main site is working fine over HTTPS but a sub domain is not.

I had a .htaccess file on the sub domain, I removed it. I created a test folder inside the sub domain and put an index.html there.

`http://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/httpstest/index.html` or `http://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/httpstest/`  works perfectly fine but `https://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/httpstest/` or `https://mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/httpstest/index.html` does not and gives a "404 Not Found" error. The SSL itself seems to be good. If I click the padlock it displays the correct information. Any help on this why is this happening and how to solve it would be very helpful.

Note: On further investigation I found that the browser is being redirected to the main domain. from any sub domain I am in , if I try HTTPS. If there is a corresponding url in the main domain for the sub domain url I was in, it takes me to that page, else it gives me a 404 error., which means it could not find the same path in the main site.

Comment: Do you have a vhost set up for the subdomain in apache ssl.conf?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It is indeed helpful. I am almost sure it wasn't added as we didn't request it to the tech support guys. They just installed the wildcard SSL.  Need to check this out with the VPS tech support guys.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, when you purchase an SSL cert, it is for a single domain. The only exception is when you purchase a wildcard cert, which will cover *.yourdomain.com.

Comment: @ChrisHenry , yep,its a wildcard cert

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, for looking at my question. We solved the problem by adding another virtual host entry in the httpd.conf file for the sub domain. But it did give rise to another problem which we are currently looking into.